# How to update mysql json column?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json

I am trying pass this object as parameter

```
{'0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeEeeeeeeeEEeE': '100000000000000000'}
```

In this function, to update mysql JSON column, but get Error:

> ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column '0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeE
>   eeeeeeeEEeE' in 'field list'

HOW TO pass this Object parameter correctly?

```
exports.update = async (jsonObj, address) => {
  console.log("jsonObj", jsonObj);

  const q = "UPDATE list SET balance = ? WHERE address = ?";
  try {
    await query(q, [jsonObj, address]);
    console.log("Updated", address);
    return "Ok";
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your SQL is wrong.  You will probably want to use **JSON_SET('the name of your JSON column','the key of the key/value pair you want to update','the new value you want for that key/value pair)**.